# How to pass array to flash message?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to send array of additional_feature that they are exist to flash message. Now i only send one additional_feature. Any suggestion how can i do that?

```
 if(!empty($additional_features)){
          foreach($additional_features as $additional_feature){
            $data = [
               'name' => $additional_feature,
             ];
             if (!Feature::where('name', '=', $additional_feature)->exists()) {
                 $additional = Feature::firstOrCreate($data);
                 $additional_ids[] = $additional->id;
             }
             else{
               return redirect()->back()->withFlashMessage($additional_feature . ' exists!');
             }

          }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `session()` instead of `with()`:

```
session->flash('someVar', $someArray);
```

Another thing you could try is to seriallize array and pass it as string. Then unserilize it and use.

Also, you could save an array using simple session:

```
session(['someVar' => $someArray]);
```

Then get it and delete manually:

```
session('somevar');
session()->forget('someVar');
```

Comment: im getting this error : Cannot access protected property Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse::$session

Comment: Are you getting this property when you're trying to get saved data from session? If so, please share the code. Also, I've added two more ways to accomplish this task.

Comment: when i use like this :  $exists_features[] = $additional_feature;

               return redirect()->back()->session(['exists' => $exists_features]);
             
i get Method [session] does not exist on Redirect.

Comment: @None, you shouldn't chain it to `redirect()`. Just use it as separate clause before redirect.

Comment: tnx ...  i just figured out what u mean :)

Answer (score 1):

We had the same problem and forked the package. you can find it here:

[Forked at first from Laracasts/Flash to use multiple message](https://packagist.org/packages/mdupaul/flash)

```
@if (Session::has('flash_notification.message'))
@if (Session::has('flash_notification.overlay'))
    @include('flash::modal', ['modalClass' => 'flash-modal', 'title' => Session::get('flash_notification.title'), 'body' => Session::get('flash_notification.message')])
@else
    <div class="alert alert-{{ Session::get('flash_notification.level') }}">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>

        {!! Session::get('flash_notification.message') !!}
    </div>
@endif
@endif
```

And the content of the include flash::modal

```
@if (Session::has('flash_notification.messages'))
@foreach (Session::get('flash_notification.messages') as $flashMessage)
    @foreach($flashMessage as $type => $message)
        <script>
            $(function() {
                var message = ('{{ $message }}<br>').replace(/'/g, "&#8217;");
                customFlashMessage({
                    type: "{{ $type }}",
                    message: message
                });
            });
        </script>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
@endif
```

Answer (score -1):

```
return redirect()->back()->with(['session1' => $value, 'session2' => $value]);
```

In the blade template:

```
{{ Session::get('session1') }}
{{ Session::get('session2') }}
```

Comment: i want to pass an array and then just to display that array in view

Comment: `->with($array)` should be fine.

Comment: ok how will i display that message in view if i use ->with($array)? :)